# generalize to a list a mongodb spring request, avoid loop for

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Here is the context:

A Person can make references to several houses via the "houseRefs" attribute.

If I want to find all the persons making reference to a given House, I use the request

```
 public List<Person> findPersons(House house){

     Query query = new Query();
     query.addCriteria(
            Criteria.where("houseRefs").in(house.getId())                
     );               
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);
}
```

I have now a list of House: 
The generalisation would be:

```
public Map<House,List<Person>> findAllPeople(List<House> houses){

    Map<House,List<Person>> map = new Map<House,List<Person>>();    

    for (House house:houses){
      map.put(house,findPersons(house));
    }

}
```

So far, so good.

Here is my request: is it possible to make a query to get in only one step a

```
  Map<House,List<Person>>
```

and avoid using a for loop ?

It is to gzt optimal results by using the internal mechanisms of mongodb rather using java loop

Something like:

```
public Map<House,List<Person>> findAllPeople(List<House> houses){

     Query query = new Query();
     query.addCriteria(
         ????              
     );               
    ??? use aggregation ???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Person> findAllPeople(List<House> houses) {
    List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (House house: houses) {
        idList.add(house.getId());
    }

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(
        Criteria.where("houseRefs").in(idList)
    );

    return mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);
}
```